# Let $A:l_1 \to c_0 : (x_k)_{k=1}^\infty \to (x_k^2)_{k=1}^\infty$. Is the operator A injective, surjective, continous, homeomorphism?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Let $A:l_1 \to c_0 : (x_k)_{k=1}^\infty \mapsto (x_k^2)_{k=1}^\infty$. Is the operator A injective, surjective, continous, homeomorphism?

For homeomorphism if I show first three(it is bijective and continous) then only remaining part is showing $A^{-1}$ is continous.

Since  $ \sum |x_n| < \infty \implies x_n  \to 0$, intuitively A should be bijective operator thus both injective and surjective. But how I can show this properly?

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by $c_0$? There is no uniform symbolism in these matters

Comment: @TommasoSeneci I'd be surprised if it meant anything other than the sequences that have limit $0.$

Comment: Third paragraph, should be $\sum |x_n|< \infty$ Also, are these real sequences?

Comment: @zhw. yes they are

Comment: @TommasoSeneci as zhw. said $c_o$ is the set of sequences that have limit  0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hints: injectivity: $A(-1,1,0,0,\dots) = A(1,1,0,0,,\dots).$

surjectivity: Is $(-1,0,0,0,\dots)$ in the range of $A?$

homeomorphism: not much hope at this point is there?

continuity: If we let $x,y\in B_{l^1}(0,R),$ then $\|Ay-Ax\|_{c_0} \le 2R\|y-x\|_{l^1}.$ (Thanks to @DanielWainfleet for correcting an error I had here at first.)

Comment: If $c_0$ has the $\sup$ norm then with $v(n)=(n,0,0,0,...)$ we have  $\|A(v(n))-A(0)\|_{c_0}=n^2$ and $\|v(n)-0\|=n$..... However if $A$ is continuous on every bounded subset of $l_1$ then $A$ would be continuous.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet  Thanks for finding that error. I've edited my answer.